# OWL 2 rolification

Tags: owl, swrl, description-logic

In description logic, there is a concept called "rolification" ([OWL and Rules, Sec 3.2](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-23032-5_7)). It converts a concept (class) into a role (property). For example, when we rolify `R(x)`, we get `r(x,x)`. This technique is useful for expressing some rules in DL.

How do we do this in OWL 2? It seems that there is no direct support for rolification in [OWL 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/).

Comment: The link to §3.2 is broken. 

Comment: @JimL. Thanks. The link is updated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Section 3.2 of the paper that you linked to says:

> It is indeed possible to translate this rule into OWL 2—however this involves a transformation which we call rolification: The rolification of a concept *A* is a (new) role *R<sub>A</sub>* defined by the axiom *A ≡ ∃R<sub>A</sub>.Self*. Armed with rolification, we can now express rule (1) by the axiom …

OWL2 doesn't support expressing an axiom like *Elephant(x) ∧ Mouse(y) → biggerThan(x,y)* directly.  As I understand it, you *manually* use the process of rolification that the paper describes to produce a new axiom that can be expressed in OWL2 directly.

### Rolification

As to the specific process, if you want to express something like *Elephant(x) ∧ Mouse(y) → biggerThan(x,y)*, you first rolify the classes *Elephant* and *Mouse*.  This means that you introduce new roles (properties) *R<sub>Elephant</sub>* and *R<sub>Mouse</sub>* (but you do not delete the classes *Elephant* and *Mouse*).  These new roles are such that *R<sub>Elephant</sub>(x,x)* if and only if *Elephant(x)*.  This is enforced by adding the axioms

Elephant ≡ ∃R<sub>Elephant</sub>.Self

Mouse ≡ ∃R<sub>Mouse</sub>.Self

each of which is expressible in OWL2.  With those two axioms in hand, you finally add the subproperty chain axiom

R<sub>Elephant</sub> • topObjectProperty • R<sub>Mouse</sub> ⊑ biggerThan

which is also expressible in OWL2. Since for any elephant *e* and any mouse *m*, we have that

R<sub>Elephant</sub>(e,e)

topObjectProperty(e,m)

R<sub>Mouse</sub>(m,m)

then by the subproperty chain axiom, we have that

biggerThan(e,m)

which is exactly what we wanted to express.

### Axiom Syntax

In the input syntax accepted by Protege, these axioms are written as follows.

Elephant **EquivalentTo** R_Elephant **some Self**
        Mouse **EquivalentTo** R_Mouse **some Self**
        R_Elephant **o** topObjectProperty **o** R_mouse **SubPropertyOf** biggerThan

In Protege they appear as follows.

[image: elephant rolification axiom]
[image: mouse rolification axiom]
[image: subproperty chain axiom]

In N3:

```
@prefix :        <http://www.example.org/rolification#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:Elephant
      a       owl:Class ;
      owl:equivalentClass
              [ a       owl:Restriction ;
                owl:hasSelf "true"^^xsd:boolean ;
                owl:onProperty :R_Elephant
              ] .

:R_Elephant
      a       owl:ObjectProperty .

:biggerThan
      a       owl:ObjectProperty ;
      owl:propertyChainAxiom
              (:R_Elephant owl:topObjectProperty :R_Mouse) .

:Mouse
      a       owl:Class ;
      owl:equivalentClass
              [ a       owl:Restriction ;
                owl:hasSelf "true"^^xsd:boolean ;
                owl:onProperty :R_Mouse
              ] .

<http://www.example.org/rolification>
      a       owl:Ontology .

:R_Mouse
      a       owl:ObjectProperty .
```

In RDF/XML:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns="http://www.example.org/rolification#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rolification"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rolification#Elephant">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rolification#R_Elephant"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:hasSelf rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean"
        >true</owl:hasSelf>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rolification#Mouse">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rolification#R_Mouse"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:hasSelf rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean"
        >true</owl:hasSelf>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rolification#biggerThan">
    <owl:propertyChainAxiom rdf:parseType="Collection">
      <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rolification#R_Elephant"/>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#topObjectProperty"/>
      <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rolification#R_Mouse"/>
    </owl:propertyChainAxiom>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, but my problem is if OWL 2 supports rolification. I browsed through the language specification, but it did not mention that.

Comment: each of which is expressible in OWL2 - so how's it expressed in OWL 2? (I know it can be expressed in description logic)

Comment: @Yang I've updated my answer with the Protégé input syntax and screenshots, as well as the N3 and RDF/XML serializations of an ontology containing these axioms.

Comment: @Yang "Rolification" isn't something that a language would typically support or not support.  It's a translation of certain kinds of sentences in to (sets) of other kinds of sentences.  A language (e.g., a particular description logic, or OWL) might not support the first kind of sentence, but might support the second kind of sentence. That's the case here;  OWL2 doesn't support the first kind of sentence, but it supports the kinds of sentences that rolification produces.

Comment: I think `hasSelf` is not rolification. It is a restriction that produces a class from a property. http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Self-Restriction

Comment: @Yang As you say, `hasSelf` is not rolification, it is a particular kind of restriction.  The paper that you linked to says: “The rolification of a concept `A` is a (new) role `R_A` defined by the axiom `A EquivalentTo some R_A Self`.”  The rolification of the class _is_ the new role.  By using the rolifications of classes, we can express things in OWL2 that we could not express in OWL2 without the rolifications of the classes.

Comment: @Yang Compare to the case of n-ary properties in OWL.  OWL only has binary properties.  But we can _represent_ arbitrary properties in OWL by _adding a new class and properties_ to represent the property.  E.g., instead of _between(x,y,z)_ we use _betweenRelation(w)_, _firstArg(w,x)_, _secondArg(w,y)_, _thirdArg(w,z)_.  Similarly, we can't write _Elephant(x) & Mouse(y) -> biggerThan(x,y)_ in OWL, but we can introduce two new roles `R_elephant` and `R_mouse` and get the same result.

Comment: I see. I think I misunderstood how we define classes and properties. Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @Yang Glad to help!  Thanks for pointing out this paper, it's got a lot of useful stuff.  I hadn't heard of "rolification" before, but it actually might pretty useful to me in the near future!