# How to find the instances having a specific relation with a given instance in an ontology using FuXi?

Tags: python, instance, ontology, reasoning

I have developed an ontology in Protege which will carry my data (as instances of the ontology) inside it along with their relations with each other (I developed it based on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30374169/1388084)).

The instantiated ontology file could be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B08SxHl0NiuvdmhYNVhnSGlYd2c). Now I want to use it in another algorithm I have developed in Python.

My goal is to traverse over the individuals in my ontology and use the knowledge in the A-box of the ontology about relations between them, i.e.

If one street is built of two lanes. This information which is either in the ontology or reasoned can help the other algorithm (written in python) in its purpose.
A
ccordingly, I have the following two questions:

1. Does anyone know how to find an instance having a special relation with a given instance using FuXi? For example in the enclosed ontology above, I want to find arc_003 which builds detailed_part_001 with arc_002. they have some more other relations in between.
2. To teach me how to fish; does anyone know some expressive and explanatory documents with some code samples of FuXi? the [FuXi document](http://fuxi.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/index.html#fuxi-sparql) is not really helpful and is complex for me.