# What are the characteristics of "Target for key" and "General class axioms" in the description of the class?

Tags: protege

Actually the question in the header. When should I use these properties? I tried to change them but nothing happened. Could someone explain me that?

Answer (score 2):

Target for Key represents HasKey in OWL2.

> An **HasKey** axiom states that each named instance of a class is uniquely identified by a (data or object) property or a set of properties - that is, if two named instances of the class coincide on values for each of key properties, then these two individuals are the same.

An example is:

```
RegisteredPatient HasKey: hasWaitingListN
```

General class expressions represent [Complex class expressions](http://ontogenesis.knowledgeblog.org/1288). They are not often used but you can use them to express complex statements in OWL.

For example:

```
HeartDisease EquivalentTo: Disease and hasLocation some Heart
```

Also, take a look at this [great example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719287/owl-protege-how-can-i-describe-a-class-that-has-just-some-properties) on how to define complex class expressions.