# What is General Class Axiom used for?

Tags: semantic-web, owl

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719287/owl-protege-how-can-i-describe-a-class-that-has-just-some-properties) shows an example of General Class Axiom:

```
((walksLike some Duck) and (talksLike some Duck)) SubClassOf Duck
```

Isn't it the same as giving a necessary and sufficient condition on Duck?

```
Duck EquivalentTo: ((walksLike some Duck) and (talksLike some Duck))
```

Aren't they logically equivalent? I've read [this article](http://ontogenesis.knowledgeblog.org/1288) as well, but I don't understand what General Class Axiom's real use for.

Comment: Why do you think that equivalence is the same as subsumption? Equivalence is a subsumption in both directions, i.e. if you have `A EquivalentTo B` it holds that `A SubClassOf B` and `B SubClassOf A`.

Comment: @AKSW Because I cannot find an example that differentiates inference results in these two cases. That is, the one should be subsumed to the Class Duck in the case of General Class Axiom and not in the case of EquivalentTo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subsumption provides only one of `necessary` or `sufficient`, as AKWS remarked.

Example:

`A1 instanceOf Duck`

`A2 instanceOf (walksLike some Duck)`
`A2 instanceOf (talksLike some Duck)`

With just the subsumption axiom, the queries:

Instances of `Duck`: `A1, A2`
Instances of `walksLike some Duck`: `A2`

With the equivalence axiom:

Instances of `Duck`: `A1, A2`
Instances of `walksLike some Duck`: `A1, A2`