# How to infer isBrotherOf property between two individuals

Tags: rdf, ontology, owl, protege

I need to infer that one individual is the brother of other one if they have the same father.

So, if I have this:

> Bart hasFather Homer.
>
> Lisa hasFather Homer.

Because `Bart` and `Lisa` have the same father, I would like to infer:

> Lisa hasBrother Bart.

Is there any method to do that using any property characteristics?

Comment: A shame that a situation that intuitive and common has such an overcomplicated representation in OWL...

Comment: @loopasam It's less complicated if other properties have been defined.  For instance, if Ortzi had used, instead, `Homer hasSon Bart`, and `Homer hasDaugher Lisa`, and declared that `hasSon` and `hasDaughter` are subproperties of `hasChild`, and defined `hasParent` as an inverse to `hasChild`, then `hasBrother` would just be `hasParent o hasSon`.  (That wouldn't handle the man is his own brother issue, though.)  The complexity of the solution depends on the expressiveness of the existing representation.  (Maybe I should add this to my answer…)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Use Property Chains and Rolification

[Antoine Zimmermann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19565141/1281433) is a very good start to this problem, and touches on the major point that you need to solve this sort of task:

> From *x* to each of *x*'s brothers, there is a path of the form *hasFather o hasFather<sup>-1</sup>*.

Now, that's actually not true of just brothers, though.  That's true for all siblings and for *x* itself.  This means you'll have the following definition of *hasSibling*:

> hasSibling ≡ hasFather o hasFather<sup>-1</sup>

(Actually, that's really just *hasPaternalSibling*; a more refined definition would use *hasParent*.)  Now, using this, you could ask for brothers, which are simply siblings who are men, of *x* with a query like:

> (hasSibling value x) and Man

However, it *would* be nice to define a proper *hasBrother* property.  You could do this with a property chain and *hasSibling* if you had a special property that linked each *Man* to himself, and only linked males to themselves:

> hasBrother ≡ hasSibling o specialProperty

In fact, such a property is what we get from a technique called *rolification*, which has been described more in a question, [OWL 2 rolification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16989042/1281433), and its answer.  The idea is that for the class *Man*, we create a new property *r<sub>Man</sub>* and add the equivalence:

> Man ≡ r<sub>Man</sub> some Self

which says that each *Man* is related to himself by the *r<sub>Man</sub>* property, and that *only* instances of *Man* are so connected.  This is exactly the property that we need as *specialProperty* above.  Thus, we end up with the following definitions of *Man*, *hasSibling*, and *hasBrother*:

[image: definition of Man]
[image: definition of hasSibling]
[image: definition of hasBrother]

Now we can ask for the brothers of *x* with a query like:

> hasBrother<sup>-1</sup> value x

For instance, we can ask for *Greg*'s siblings, and get *Peter*, *Greg* (himself), and *Bobby*.

[image: example of query]

### Sample Ontology

Here's that ontology in Turtle:

```
@prefix :      <http://www.example.org/brady#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix brady: <http://www.example.org/brady#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

brady:hasSibling  a             owl:ObjectProperty ;
        owl:propertyChainAxiom  ( brady:hasFather [ owl:inverseOf
                          brady:hasFather ] ) .

brady:Carol  a  owl:NamedIndividual , brady:Woman .

brady:hasBrother  a             owl:ObjectProperty ;
        owl:propertyChainAxiom  ( brady:hasSibling brady:r_Man ) .

<http://www.example.org/brady>
        a       owl:Ontology .

brady:Woman  a               owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf      brady:Person ;
        owl:equivalentClass  [ a               owl:Restriction ;
                               owl:hasSelf     true ;
                               owl:onProperty  brady:r_Woman
                             ] .

brady:hasFather  a  owl:ObjectProperty .

brady:Person  a  owl:Class .

brady:Man  a                 owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf      brady:Person ;
        owl:equivalentClass  [ a               owl:Restriction ;
                               owl:hasSelf     true ;
                               owl:onProperty  brady:r_Man
                             ] .

brady:r_Woman  a  owl:ObjectProperty .

brady:r_Man  a  owl:ObjectProperty .

brady:Marcia  a          owl:NamedIndividual , brady:Woman ;
        brady:hasFather  brady:Mike .

brady:Peter  a           owl:NamedIndividual , brady:Man ;
        brady:hasFather  brady:Mike .

brady:Jan  a             owl:NamedIndividual , brady:Woman ;
        brady:hasFather  brady:Mike .

brady:Cindy  a           owl:NamedIndividual , brady:Woman ;
        brady:hasFather  brady:Mike .

brady:Bobby  a           owl:NamedIndividual , brady:Man ;
        brady:hasFather  brady:Mike .

brady:Greg  a            owl:NamedIndividual , brady:Man ;
        brady:hasFather  brady:Mike .

brady:Mike  a   owl:NamedIndividual , brady:Man .
```

Comment: Unbelievable answer! Thanks.

Comment: I have a question about the answer. In that solution, if we have two brothers A and B, the infered result shows that A hasSibling B, but also shows that A hasSibling A. Could it be solved?

Comment: @jartymcfly That's a good observation, and there aren't very good solutions to work around it, unfortunately.  Depending on your use case, the best thing might just be to filter out those results.  E.g., see the comments on [AntoineZimmermann's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19565141/1281433).

Comment: what is an "o" here in this statement ? "hasFather o  inverse (hasFather)"

Comment: @crapthings It's property composition, or a property chain, in OWL terminology.  E.g., if `Joe fatherOf Tim` and `Tim brotherOf Hank`, then  `Joe fatherOf o brotherOf Hank`.  In the Manchester syntax (that Protege uses), you input it with just a lowercase letter "o".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that everyone is their own brother, and that sisters are brothers too:

```
:hasBrother  owl:propertyChainAxiom  (:hasFather [ owl:inverseOf :hasFather ]) .
```

It is hardly possible to define :hasBrother more precisely, excluding female brothers and self-brotherhood. But you can infer all the brothers of Lisa as follows:

```
:Female  a  owl:Class .
:Male  a  owl:Class;
  owl:disjointWith  :Female .
:Lisa  a  :Female .
:Bart  a  :Male .
:Homer a  :Male .
:hasFather  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
  rdfs:range  :Male .
:hasBrother a  owl:ObjectProperty;
  rdfs:range  :Male .
:hasSiblingOrSelf  owl:propertyChainAxiom  ( :hasFather [ :hasFather ] ) .
:LisaBrother  owl:equivalentClass  [
    a  owl:Restriction;
    owl:onProperty  [ owl:inverseOf  :hasBrother ];
    owl:hasValue  :Lisa
  ], [
    a  owl:Class;
    owl:intersectionOf  (
      [ a owl:Restriction; owl:onProperty :hasSiblingOrSelf; owl:hasValue :Lisa ]
      :Male
    )
  ] .
```

Comment: Using [rolification](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16989042/1281433) and a **Female** class, I think you could actually exclude sisters pretty easily.  I'm not sure whether you could easily exclude self-brothers, though.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The last hard thing is to exclude being brother of oneself. I don't know how to do it if it is at all possible, in OWL.

Answer (score 1):

One way to this is by using SWRL rules.

On protege:

1. go to Window
2. Click on Tabs
3. Click on Swrl Tab
4. Press the "new" button and write the following rule

Write rule:

```
isChildOf(?x,?y)^FatherOf(?y,?z)^differentFrom(?z,?x)->isBrotherOf(?x,?z)
```

This means that if "x is a child of y", and "y is also a parent of z" and "z and x are different" then "z and x are Brothers".

Answer (score 0):

A brother is a male sibling. Consequently, we should define both 'male' and being a sibling. But since a sibling is itself a non-identical child of the same parents, one should also define being a child. For simplicity, we'll treat half-siblings as siblings, restrict the domain to humans, and leave the explicit definition of related concepts like motherhood and fatherhood aside.

## 1 Define Man

1. Create a `Human` class
2. Create a `Gender` class disjoint with the `Human` class. Create `male` and `female` as individuals instantiating the `Gender` type (there are other ways to do this, but this is a pretty simple one).
3. Create a `hasGender` Object property, with `Human` as domain and `Gender` for its range
4. Create a `Man` class as a subclass of `Human`. Make it equivalent to `Human and (hasGender value male)`.

## 2 Define child

5. Create an `isChildOf` Object property with Human for both its domain and range (Optional: Define a `Child` class as a subtype of human equivalent to `isChildOf some Human`. In similar fashion, you can also create object properties, then classes for `Mother`, `Parent`, `Daughter`, etc).

## 3 Define sibling with help from SWRL

6. First, create an irreflexive, symmetric `isSiblingOf` object property in Protege with `Human` for its domain and range.
7. In the menu bar at the top of Protege, ensure Window -> tabs -> SWRLTab is checked and then find and click on the SWRLTab tab.
8. Click new to create a new rule, and add the rule: `isChildOf(?sibling1, ?parent) ^ isChildOf(?sibling2, ?parent) ^ differentFrom(?sibling1, ?sibling2) -> isSiblingOf(?sibling1, ?sibling2)`
   You may also want to add rules for what you want to be able to infer from the siblinghood relation, e.g `isSiblingOf(?x, ?y) ^ isChildOf(?x, z?) -> isChildOf(?y, ?z)`

## 4 Define being a brother of

9. Create an `isBrotherOf` Object property in Protege with domain `Man` and range `Human`
10. On the SWRLTab, add the following rules:
    `Man(?x) ^ isSiblingOf(?x, ?y) -> isBrotherOf(?x, ?y)`

`isBrotherOf(?x, ?y) -> Man(?x)`

`isBrotherOf(?x, ?y) -> isSiblingOf(?x, ?y)`

The first rule states that any male sibling is a brother. The second and third infer maleness and siblinghood from brotherhood.

11. Optionally create a `Brother` class equivalent to `isBrotherOf some Human` to complete the rollification process.