# Irreflexive object property isSiblingOf in OWL 2

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I would like to infer all siblings of person p, except of p himself. I use Protege 4.3.0 and object property isSiblingOf:
 
`isChildOf o isParentOf SubPropertyOf isSiblingOf` 
It works quite well, but naturally it also infers that person is sibling of himself. It is not possible to use “irreflexive” option in object property isSiblingOf.
Basically, I would like to continue in question [How to infer isBrotherOf property between two individuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559651/how-to-infer-isbrotherof-property-between-two-individuals) where last two comments end with dilemma whether it is possible or not. 
If it is possible, how?

Comment: I *think* this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is by using SWRL rules. On Protege,

1. Go to Window
2. Go to Tabs
3. Click on SWRL tab
4. Write the rule:

```
isChildOf(?x,?y)^ParentOf(?y,?z)^differentFrom(?z,?x)->isSibling(?x,?z)
```

This means that if "x is a child of y", and "y is also a parent of z" and "z and x are different" then "z and x are siblings".