# OWL. How to express that siblings has common parent?

Tags: rdf, semantics, semantic-web, owl

I wrote simple file in turtle notation where Dave is father of Mary and Mary sister of Jack. I want reason that Dave have two childs Jack and Mary.

```
:Human a rdfs:Class .

:Man rdfs:subClassOf :Human ;
  owl:disjointWith :Woman .
:Woman rdfs:subClassOf :Human ;
  owl:disjointWith :Man .


:hasChild a rdf:Property ;
  owl:inverseOf :hasParent ;
  rdfs:domain :Human ;
  rdfs:range :Human.

:fatherOf owl:InverseFunctionalProperty rdf:Property ;
  owl:inverseOf :hasFather ;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasChild ;
  rdfs:domain :Man ;
  rdfs:range :Human.

:motherOf owl:InverseFunctionalProperty rdf:Property ;
  owl:inverseOf :hasMother ;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasChild ;
  rdfs:domain :Woman ;
  rdfs:range :Human.


:siblingOf a owl:SymmetricProperty, owl:TransitiveProperty ;
  owl:inverseOf :hasSibling ;
  rdfs:domain :Human ;
  rdfs:range :Human.

:brotherOf a rdf:Property ;
  owl:inverseOf :hasBrother ;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf :siblingOf ;
  rdfs:domain :Man ;
  rdfs:range :Human.

:sisterOf a rdf:Property ;
  owl:inverseOf :hasSister ;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf :siblingOf ;
  rdfs:domain :Woman ;
  rdfs:range :Human.



[] rdf:type owl:Axiom ;
   owl:subject    :Man ;
   owl:predicate  rdfs:subClassOf ;
   owl:object     :Human ;
   rdfs:label     "States that every man is a human."^^xsd:string .

[] rdf:type owl:Axiom ;
   owl:subject    :Woman ;
   owl:predicate  rdfs:subClassOf ;
   owl:object     :Human ;
   rdfs:label     "States that every woman is a human."^^xsd:string .


:Dave a :Man .

:Jack a :Man ;
   :hasSister :Mary .

:Mary a :Woman ;
   :hasFather :Dave .
```

I've read http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#Property, http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-owl-semantics-20021108/syntax.html#2.3.1.3 but still don't understand how to express this simple fact.

Comment: You may find [How to infer isBrotherOf property between two individuals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559651/how-to-infer-isbrotherof-property-between-two-individuals) useful, though it's not an exact answer for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Dave is father of Mary and Mary sister of Jack. I want reason that Dave have two childs Jack and Mary.*

If you ignore the possibility of siblings having different parents (e.g., a parent in common and a different parent), then you can do this with subproperty chains.  If you have data like:

Dave →<sub>hasChild</sub> Mary →<sub>hasSibling</sub> Jack

then you'd want to use the rule that:

hasChild • hasSibling ⊑ hasChild

That would allow you to infer that:

Dave →<sub>hasChild</sub> Jack

In Turtle that could look like this:

```
@prefix :      <http://stackoverflow.com/a/30903421/1281433/> .
@prefix a:     <http://stackoverflow.com/a/30903421/1281433/> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

a:Jack  a       owl:NamedIndividual .

a:Dave  a           owl:NamedIndividual ;
        a:hasChild  a:Mary .

a:hasChild  a                   owl:ObjectProperty ;
        owl:propertyChainAxiom  ( a:hasChild a:hasSibling ) .

a:Mary  a             owl:NamedIndividual ;
        a:hasSibling  a:Jack .

a:hasSibling  a  owl:ObjectProperty .

a:      a       owl:Ontology .
```

Here's the conclusion derived in Protege:

[image: sibling inference]

Comment: We know that `Jack :hasSibling Mary` and `Mary :hasSibling Jack`, due to transitivity `Mary :hasSibling Mary` and `Jack :hasSibling Jack`. How we can redefine `:hasSibling` property ?

Comment: @4ell I'm not sure quite what you're asking.  Can you give an example of what you want to infer from what?

Comment: From a fact `Jack :hasSibling Mary` I want to infer only `Mary :hasSibling Jack` excluding :hasSibling on itself like `Jack :hasSibling Jack`

Comment: @4ell I'm not sure that you'll be able to do that in OWL.