# Where is documentation on the OWL DL operator "o"?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I was reading the answer to this question:
[How to infer isBrotherOf property between two individuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559651/how-to-infer-isbrotherof-property-between-two-individuals/19565141#19565141)

In the screenshots there are class expressions which use an operator "o". I've scoured the OWL 2 documentation and could not find this defined anywhere. Google searching for "o" does not yield anything, as it's probably a stop-word.

Where is the "manual page" for this "o"?

Answer (score 3):

The `o` operator is more Description Logic syntax style and means the concatenation of object property expressions, i.e. object properties or its inverse. In OWL 2 this is covered in so-called [property chains](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#Property_Chains)

Moreover, the operator is used in [Manchester OWL syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/) which is the default syntax in Protege (the screenshot you refer to shows the Protege ontology editor)

Comment: I still don't get it. Is `o` a short-hand for `ObjectPropertyChain`?

Comment: Yes, it's, on the one hand, the notation from another syntax called Description Logic but also used in Manchester OWL syntax(https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/) which is the default syntax in Protege.