# Using Property Chains to get inferred Knowledge in an OWL Ontology(Protege)

Tags: owl, protege, description-logic

I have modelled the following in my Ontology:

Club employs some Player, Player hasNationality some Nationality, Player hasNationalStatus value National_Player, Country is equivalent to Nationality.

I want the Ontology to infer that:

If a Player hasNationality some Nationality  and, Player hasNationalStatus value National_Player then, Country(Same as the nationality the player has) employs Player.

As an example:

{Steven_Gerrard} hasNationality value England and, {Steven_Gerrard} hasNationalStatus value National_Player therefore, {England} employs [Steven_Gerrard}.

Is there a possible way to add this knowledge to Protege?

Thanks.

Edit:

Error Messages:

Error 42 Logged at Tue Apr 01 20:49:24 BST 2014

OWLReasonerRuntimeException: Non-simple object property 'http://www.semanticweb.org/u1cjd/ontologies/2014/1/untitled-ontology-2#employs' is used as a simple one

and

Error 43 Logged at Tue Apr 01 20:49:24 BST 2014
ReasonerInternalException: tRole.cpp:243: assertion 'Ancestor.empty() && Descendant.empty()' fails

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is possible, and it's actually very similar to the technique I mentioned in an answer to your previous question, [Adding statements of knowledge to an OWL Ontology in Protege)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22688901/1281433), and the structure of this answer is almost identical to my answer to a recent answers.semanticweb.com question, [OWL property inference from blank node - modelling](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/27254/owl-property-inference-from-blank-node-modelling).

You just need to use some [rolification](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bowl%5D%20rolification%20is:answer) and a property chain axiom.  The point to note is that the existing data has the form of the upper arrows, and the desired information is in the lower arrows.

[image: diagrm]

It's not enough to give *employs* the subproperty *hasNationality<sup>-1</sup>*, because you want to ensure that the player has a particular national status.  This is where you need rolification. You want *employs* to have a subproperty chain of *hasNationality<sup>-1</sup> • p*, where *p* is a special property that only relates players with national status to themselves.  You can do that with rolification.  Just declare a new object property *R<sub>NationalPlayers</sub>* and assert the axioms

> 1. hasNationalStatus **value** National_Player **EquivalentTo** R_NationalPlayer **some Self**
> 2. **inverse**(hasNationality) **o** R_NationalPlayer **subPropertyOf** employs

In the description logic syntax, these would be something like:

> 1. =hasNationalStatus.National_Player ≡ ∃R<sub>NationalPlayer</sub>.**Self**
> 2. hasNationality<sup>-1</sup> • R<sub>NationalPlayer</sub> ⊑ employs

This will work in some reasoners, but unfortunately, this does bring us out of OWL 2 DL and into OWL full.  This was discussed in some detail in the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20199283/1281433).  As the error message in the updated question indicates, *employs* is now a non-simple property, and used in a place where only simple properties should be used.  See [11.1 Property Hierarchy and Simple Object Property Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Property_Hierarchy_and_Simple_Object_Property_Expressions) for more about what makes a property simple or not, and [11.2 The Restrictions on the Axiom Closure](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#The_Restrictions_on_the_Axiom_Closure) for more about properties can appear where.

However, it sounds like you're using a reasoner that supports SWRL rules, in which case you could simply add the rule:

> hasNationality(?player,?country) ∧ hasNationalStatus(?player,National_Player) → employs(?country,?player)

Comment: So 1. is a new ObjectProperty?

Comment: Yes, the new property, R\_NationalPlayer, has the special feature that it only relates individuals that have a national status of  national player to themselves.  It's called the _rolification_ of the class (hasNationalStatus value NationalPlayer), and it's only really useful in helping to ensuring that a property chain "goes where you want it to".

Comment: This gives two error message when I try to reason with FaCT++.I'll add them to the main post.

Comment: @ChrisDLFC It might bring you out of OWL DL into OWL Full.

Comment: To make sure I have everything correct, I add R_NationalPlayer as a new role(ObjectProperty), "hasNationalStatus value National_Player EquivalentTo R_NationalPlayer some  Self" as a General Class Axiom and " inverse (hasNationality) o R_NationalPlayer SubPropertyOf employs" as a chain of employs?

Comment: @ChrisDLFC You have it right, and the error message is correct:  this construction brings you out of OWL 2 DL, and some reasoners will reject it (others might work with it).  As a simpler alternative, you could use a SWRL rule.  Many reasoners handle SWRL rules, and you won't need to do any rolification at all.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: And this statement would also go in General Class Axioms as well?

Comment: No, it's a SWRL rule, so you'd add it under the Rules view. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21499584/1281433) includes how to add it, if it's not already there (although you can add the view to an existing tab, you don't _have_ to create a new tab).  Then you'd type in the rule as `hasNationality(?player,?country), hasNationalStatus(?player,National_Player) -> employs(?country,?player)`.

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant and much easier to understand for me as well, I can add a lot of other things I wanted to add now as well in a similar format.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I apologize first as I am not sure if this's a morally correct way to notify you about my question, as you may have already seen it, but I am really hoping that you can kindly help me with almost the same issue but a bit more complex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457344/swrl-and-rolification-cannot-return-what-i-want

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor this is a great question and answer.  I tried to implement the OWL property chain solution but haven't succeeded yet.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978428/unsuccessful-team-employs-player-property-chain