# Is it possible to add customized rules to infer new relations in AllegroGraph?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, rdfs, allegrograph

In my data there are two triples:

```
entity1 doA entity2 .
entity2 doB entity3 .
```

I am looking for a way to infer the following triple and have it back in the outcome of my SPARQL query (e.g., `select ?a ?c {?a doC ?c)`) :

```
entity1 doC entity3 .
```

Basically, I want to say:

> IF (?a doA ?b) and (?b doB ?c) THEN (?a doC ?c)

Note, I am looking for a solution that can be completely implemented using the AGWebView interface.

Comment: AllegroGraph is an RDF store so should be able to apply inference rules with OWL and/or RDFS statements and load through the Web View. I don't have a definite answer for you inference issue but it sounds like you require OWL 2 property chains [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792359/using-property-chains-to-get-inferred-knowledge-in-an-owl-ontologyprotege] [http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/].

Comment: If you're not locked into AllegroGraph, Stardog offers almost *exactly* the syntax you describe for its rule language, which uses the SWRL semantics.

Comment: @Michael thanks, I will give it a try if I find it is almost impossible to achieve it with AG.

Comment: @AnthonyHughes thanks for pointing out OWL2 property chain. seems exactly the feature that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If AllegroGraph supports SPARQL 1.1m then you could try:

```
INSERT {?a <doC> ?c}
WHERE {
   ?a <doA> ?b .
   ?b <doB> ?c .
}
```

That inserts into the default graph, however that is defined.  To direct to a specific graph, then add a GRAPH statement to the insert:

```
INSERT { GRAPH <graph-uri> {
            ?a <doC> ?c}
       }
    ...
```

Comment: thanks. sounds like an interesting solution. Just wondering if this will insert all possible edges to the graph. For example,

Comment: sorry, my previous comment was incomplete. Please read this one: thanks. sounds like an interesting solution. Just wondering if this will insert all possible edges to the graph. For example, suppose I have initially <a,x,c> and <c,x,d> and <d,x,e>. Then, I run the INSERT query only ONCE.    I think obviously the INSERT command will generate <a,x,d> and <c,x,e>. Now I am curious if it also automatically  includes <a,x,e>?

Comment: This is a separate example.  In the original, you specified three different properties <doA>, <doB>, <doC>.  And no, {<a> <x> <e>} would not be created. However, for your new question I'm guessing your notation assumes the same property, <x>, so you're basically asking for the transitive closure.  here seems to be asking for the transitive closure. This can be done by SPARQL property paths, i.e. INSERT {?s <x> ?o} WHERE { ?s <x>* ?o}, where the '*' on the property indicates finding all transitive relationships of <x>.

Comment: right, I was looking for transitive closure. The new query seems what I have been looking for. Thanks for the answer.