# Trouble Inferring Properties for Classes/Individuals in Protege 5/OWL

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, protege, rdfs

I want to be able to infer which ingredients go well together given...their properties and which properties complement each other.

I have an ontology like,

```
owl:Thing
    Ingredient
        Kale
        Pear
    Taste
        Bitter
        Sweet

owl:topObjectProperty
    hasTaste
    tasteComplements
    goesWellWith

Individuals: (*would rather work with just classes)
    kale a Kale
    pear a Pear
    bitter a Bitter
    sweet a Sweet
```

I've asserted,

```
Kale subClassOf hasTaste some Bitter
Pear subClassOf hasTaste some Sweet
Bitter subClassOf tasteComplements some Sweet

tasteComplements a owl:SymmetricProperty
goesWellWith a owl:SymmetricProperty
```

And a general axiom:

```
(hasTaste some Bitter) SubClassOf: goesWellWith some (hasTaste some Sweet)
```

First of all, I'd like Protege to be able to infer that also `Sweet tasteComplements some Bitter`. Although I understand why symmetric properties in existential restrictions don't work that way. So I'll settle for

```
sweet tasteComplements bitter
bitter tasteComplements sweet
```

But surprisingly neither of these are inferred. I must manually specify one of them first, then the other is inferred.

More importantly I want to infer:

```
Kale goesWellWith some Pear
Pear goesWellWith some Kale
```

while failing in this, I'd at least like:

```
kale goesWellWith pear
```

But this is not inferred either. From my general axiom, it should be the case that since `kale a Kale`, there necessarily must be at least one triple:

```
kale hasTaste [b]    <!-- where [b] is of type Bitter -->
```

Therefore, we have should another triple too:

```
kale goesWellWith [y]
```

where

```
[y] hasTaste [s]   <!-- and [s] is of type Sweet --> 
[y] is pear        <!-- the only available option in this case -->
kale goesWellWith pear
```

How can I make these inferences happen between individuals as expected? Something between classes would be even better.*

More generally, I'd like to be able to assert:

```
if XXX tasteComplements YYY then:
    (hasTaste some XXX) SubClassOf: goesWellWith some (hasTaste some YYY)
```

Is there some sneaky way to achieve this with rolification like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792359/using-property-chains-to-get-inferred-knowledge-in-an-owl-ontologyprotege)? (I'd rather avoid SWRL rules...)

*
***NOTE***

I would rather infer triples between classes rather than individuals, although I know of no way to make this logically happen. Individuals feel like a laundry list/dump of every concept in my ingredients & properties taxonomy with no hierarchy -- redundant and impossible to keep organized. Ideally this taxonomy will provide an interface for someone to describe the characteristics of ingredients that complement each other.

Comment: Moved this question to a more succinct one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690474/inference-on-complex-classes-in-protege