# Inference in protége

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, inference

I'm building an ontology to find peoples' skills. I want to infer that when a person A passed a course B and course B provides skill C, then person A has skill C.   Is there a way to do this in Protégé?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you're saying that when you have:

A →<sub>passed</sub> B →<sub>providesSkill</sub> C

you want to infer that

A →<sub>hasSkill</sub> C

You can do that with the subproperty chain axiom:

passed • providesSkill ⊑ hasSkill

For a more detailed example of how to add these in Protege,  see the (not quite a duplicate) question: [Adding statements of knowledge to an OWL Ontology in Protege)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22688901/1281433).