# Defining a class individuals as a combination of another class individuals

Tags: owl, modeling, reasoning, description-logic

In an OWL ontology, given a class `Student`; I want to define another class `StudentsPair`, which is any pair of students, in such a way that automatically computes all the possible dual combinations of `Student`, i.e.

```
Student(x) and Student (y) --> StudentsPair(x,y)
```

I want `StudentsPair` as a class, not a property, because it may have additional features (such as `averagePerformanceForPair`, etc.).

For example,

**Premise**

```
Student(John)
Student(Alex)
Student(Mary)
-----------------
```

**Conclusion**

```
StudentPair((John, Alex))
StudentPair((John, Mary))
StudentPair((Alex, Mary))
```

The reasoner has to somehow create these new individuals! Is this possible?

Comment: At first, it would probably easier to try to create nine pairs (3 × 3) since there's probably no great way to restrict the ordering, and it might be difficult to prevent self-pairs.  But as AKSW says, it's easy to get to the point where you can relate each student to every  other student, but it might not be possible to cause instances of another class to exist.

Answer (score 2):

You need an additional role `student`, then you can use Description Logic Rules, something like that might work:

```
Student ≡ ∃student.Self
student ◦ U ◦ student ⊑ StudentPair
```

Comment: What is `U` at the second line of your code, and did you intend `StudentPair` as a property? Because I want it a class, as I state in my question.

Comment: It can't be a class, which is an unary relation, if you have a binary relation. And `U` would be the universal role. You should know that OWL does not have variables, so you usually have to use rules. But for your case, I'm not sure how a reasoner should create pairs of instances which itself are instances of a class. That sounds like higher-order logic and not first-order logic. But I'm not sure and maybe somebody else can help you.

Comment: The construction used here is known as rolification, and has been discussed in a number of other questions, including [OWL 2 rolification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989042/owl-2-rolification).